# Run jar of Spring boot application with execution repackage and external application.yml properties

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I used the following plugin to get the executable jar of my Spring Boot application:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I got a runnable jar that contient BOOT-INF , META-INF folders.

I would like to read my file properties application.yml from an external folder in my machine called conf and with a active profile dev

The command line i used is:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.location=file:C:\conf -jar appJar.jar
```

when the app run it seems that it reads the internal application.yml in BOOT-INF and not my application.yml in the folder conf.

How can deal with this issue, am i missing something in the pom or is there any other configuration i must specify?

Comment: [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features). Scroll to the last bullet-point beginning "The search order for properties..."

Comment: thx @AndyBrown, i missed the file it self in the path C:\conf , it must be C:\conf\application.yml, the full path